# spring boot 2 authorization server - all endpoints return 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have an application with an authorization server (OAuth2) which I migrated from Spring Boot 1.X to 2.X. Whenever I try to access any of the endpoint functions (e.g. `/oauth/token` or `/oauth/token_key`) it results in HTTP-404. The service itself is up which I can see in `/actuator/health`. It was working without problems with the old Spring Boot.

I already tried to enable all services but without success. I'm using Spring Boot 2, Resilience4J, and OAuth2.

This is my code:

**AuthApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableAutoConfiguration    
public class AuthApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**AuthServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore())
                .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme").secret("acme")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
                .scopes("openid", "request", "write", "read");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");
    }
    
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and().logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .and().httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable();
            
    }
    

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

I also added this to the `bootstrap.yml` in the hope it would help, but it didn't:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Why are non of the endpoints of the authorization server available?

**EDIT 1**

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>app</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/. The `@EnableAuthorizationServer` is moved from Spring Boot 1.x in version 2 to Spring Security. That is probably the reason that whole class is not being picked up.

Comment: When removing the annotation it's still not working. As it's also annotated with `@Component` I also don't know why it should matter.

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: @Fullslack.dev: Please see the edit.

Comment: Could you check if switching from `org.springframework.security.oauth.boot` to [org.springframework.security.oauth](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2) makes a difference?